# Grails how to map enum to existing enum on database

Tags: grails, enums, grails-orm

I have a given **postgres** db using a enum type with following values "M", "F". The value can be null. When i try to save a domainobject, i receive the errors below.

postgres enum:

```
CREATE TYPE genderlist AS ENUM ('M','F')
```

my enum:

```
public enum GenderCode {

    M,F

    private final String value

    private static list

    public String value() {
        return name()
    }

    public static GenderCode fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v)
    }

}
```

domain class:

```
class UserLog {

    String gender = null //default null
    ..
}
```

BootStrap.groovy:

```
// reading - works fine now
def rows = UserLog.list()

// insert - does not work
UserLog u = new UserLog(gender:null)
u.save()
```

Error:

```
| Batch-Entry 0 insert into user_log (active, birthyear, country, gender, user_id, id) values ('1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 98304) was cancelled.  
| ERROR: column "gender" is of type genderlist but expression is of type character varying
  Note: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

---

**EDIT**
i updated the whole question to match the current state of my project. since i updated the enum i do not longer have problems on reading data. the PGObject gets casted into the String representation properly. the casting is still an issue when trying to insert data.

i have a dirty little workaround which works:

```
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource_log)
    def map = [gender:'M']

    sql.executeInsert "insert into user_log (gender) values ('${map.gender}')"
```

my question still stays the same: how do i cast the String properly **on insert?** also 'null' value is not accepted yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use your groovy gender enum in the `UserLog` domain class and set the `sqlType` of the column in the mapping for UserLog:

```
class UserLog {
    GenderCode gender = null
    ...
    static mapping = {
        gender sqlType: 'enum'
    }
}
```

Comment: results in the same type missmatch enum (database) <-> char varying (expression). but at least i can save the gender having null value. 
i tried: `UserLog u = new UserLog(gender:"M")` and `UserLog u = new UserLog(); u.gender = GenderCode.fromValue("M")` before saving.

Answer (score 0):

In grails your custom enum is stored as String. Take a look at the log

```
('1', NULL, NULL, 'M', NULL, 98304)
```

It wants to insert a String. It looks like conflict between class in your project and database. Try to remove genderList type from database.
From my expirience I defined like this:

```
public enum ActivityState {
    ACTIVE("active"),
    NOT_ACTIVE("not_active")

    private final String value

    public ActivityState(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    String toString(){
        value
    }

    public String value() {
        value
    }

    public static ActivityState byValue(String value){
        values().find { it.value == value }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
ActivityState activityState
```

Comment: unfortunately deleting the enum in the datastore is not an option.

Comment: try to add value() and byValue() methods, maybe the problem in cast from string to enum. So try to use as discribed.

Comment: @DominikH Just remove sqltype "genderlist". You don't have this type, and the database value is stored as String.

Comment: If not an option to delete, don't use it. Just rename enum.

Answer (score 0):

ok i would say i fixed it on my own by including the save via direct sql query into the domain class:

```
class UserLog{

    ...

    public saveIt(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource_log)

        sql.executeInsert """ 
            insert into user_log(gender,.. ) 
            values ('${this.gender}', .. ) 
            """

        sql.close()
    }
}
```

saving instance:

```
Dummy d = new Dummy()
d.gender = 'M'
d.saveIt()
```

anyways it would be smarter not to have this workaround, since the query has to be changed with every change on the domain.